# Order of the elements in a non-cyclic group of order 8

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of order 8 that is not cyclic. Show that $a^4=e$ for every $a \in G$.

$a^{|G|}=e$ for every $a$. So $a^8=e$. So, $o(a)$ must be 1,2, 4 or 8. If $o(a)=8$ then G is cyclic, so $o(a)$ must be 1, 2 or 4. If $a \neq e$, we have 2 or 4.  I don't Know how to proceed.

This seems false to me. Given an element k of order 4, $k^2$ has order 2.

I decided to post the question because it's an exercise from the book I'm following on groups, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: An element $a$ of order $2$ still satisfies $a^4=e$.

Comment: Sure, sure, for some reason I was interpreting it as, 'every element of G has order 4,' which is different from 'every element 'a' of G is such that $a^4=e$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct so far, except that you need to recognise, as said in the comments, that if $|a|\mid n$ for $a$ in a group $G$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, then $a^n=e.$